# PHP 5.3 - how to append contents to a large file without loading in to memory

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'm trying to efficiently write a large amount of data to a file ( I'm relatively new to PHP ) in a legacy system to a file without killing the memory. It is only writing 50 customers at a time , but after a while it slows down considerably , so I assume it is keeping the whole file in memory.  Any ideas how I can just append to a file and cope with the file getting very large? Code snippet below.  Note: I am stuck with PHP 5.3.

```
do{
     //Tell the collection which page to load.
     $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
     $collection->load();
     $fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('export') .'/customers.json', 'a');
     foreach ($collection as $customer){
        //write collection as json
        fwrite($fp, "," . json_encode($customer->getData()));
        $customerCount++;
     }
     fclose($fp);
     $currentPage++;
     //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
     $collection->clear();
     echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
     echo "Finished page $currentPage of $pages \n"; 
} while ($currentPage <= $pages);
```

Comment: was $fp opened in append mode or? there is a lot missing code from this question. add rows in  loop like this is probably not very efficient, but would use less memory than all at once, so its a trade off

Comment: check with is_writable() the file user rights

Comment: thanks @episch  I can write no problem .. the issue is memory size.

Comment: thanks @smith I have expanded the code. The memory used in the loop is very small , it just gets huge over time which tells me that the whole file is in memory and expanding.

Comment: Try commenting out the file code, the load() by itself might be what's eating memory.

Comment: Thanks @DaveS  it's Magento , so we need to load the collection.  It's only a little each time , and we run a $collection->clear() further down the code.  I think the issue is that when I am writing to the file , it is keeping the whole file in memory.

Comment: It's not doing that. The problem is somewhere in the code, whether it be yours or Magento's, not PHP's file handling.